# 404 not found page not working with my .htaccess

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I have below .htaccess on the server with the not found page rules but it doesn't seems to work. Any idea?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article_detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ article_detail.php?article_det=$2
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/main/404_not_found.html


# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML

<IfModule mod_ext_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What did you mean with not work? Did you send the 404 page inside the php script did Apache deliver the 404 error page?

Comment: what does not seem to work? it is perfectly fine. could you post error also?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Apache rather than IIS;

1. **Ensure you have mod rewrite enabled** (You can do this by locating the line below in the `httpd.conf` file (usually within the `/conf/` directory *This maybe different if you're using shared hosting* and removing the semi colon from the start of the line)

   `;LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
2. Find the relevant directory tag for your www root and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`
3. **Create an .htaccess file within the root directory (If one doesn't exist)**
4. **You'd need to insert something that looks like this**;

   `ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html`

   `ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.html`

   `ErrorDocument 401 /errordocs/401.html`

   `ErrorDocument 403 /errordocs/403.html`

   - Instead of `ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.html` you could also do `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yourdomain.com/errordocs/404.html` or even just display a simple message `ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry can't allow you access today"`
   - If you have any trouble the [Apache Manual (ErrorDocument Directive)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) should help you out further.

In your case make sure `AllowOverride All` is on, your editing the `.htaccess` file in the root and make sure you can hit the URL for the error page, if there's nothing at the URL that you specify Apache will return the default 404.

Comment: Nvm found it, after enabling at apache conf the remaining problem is the wrong configuration on the rewrite rules. Anyway thanks a bunch.

Comment: Checked on apache 2.4.10, It's not work if your url contains "%2f". Ex: http://localhost/invalid%2fsource

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `ErrorDocument 404 /main/404_not_found.html`?

Just incase you have something interfering with your URL (not sure if that is your complete htaccess)? I usually don't put the whole URL in although technically you can.

Also can you access the 404 page directly?

Answer (score 1):

In your apache configuration, in the Directory section of your website, be sure that you are allowed to override the FileInfo directive.

Somthing like

AllowOverride FileInfo

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncomment line from httpd.conf in apache configuration.

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also restart apache

Comment: It is initially uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line by ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com

If that works, that mean that the path you are using was misconfigure. I don't know your directory structure so I can give you the good code to write.

I don't think it's an .htaccess error because you'll get a 500 Internal error if it is.

If this tricks does not work, that means something redirecting inside your apache configuration.