# How to handle this kind of error index.php/something.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect this kind of request to any other page.

```
index.php/somefile.php
```

Redirect to `index.php`

I know this is illegal, I can't access a file or method this way in Core PHP. But if any user try to access any file or path that is not exists after my legal file then how can i redirect them to index or pagenotfound.

Comment: You can do this in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: how ?? Please describe in little detail

Answer (score 1):

First create error404.php page

Then Create .htaccess file. And add this code.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error404.php
```

In the error404.php add this code

```
<?php
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: Its giving internal server error. and does not loading any page

Comment: you have to create error404.php page and give location of the file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639561/404-not-found-page-not-working-with-my-htaccess     follow this link

Comment: Sorry my rewrite module was off I turn it on and create error page now internal server error gone. but redirection still not working. I want to redirect index.php/somefile.php to error404.php. remember somefile.php is not exists.

Comment: thanks for answering and commenting but I think you are not understanding my problem.

Comment: Dear this is only for one page i want to handle all requests. if evil mind user try to access a page that is not exist but he try to access after my pages that is exist on server. for example index.php is exist and somefile not exist. user writes index.php/something and header should move to error page. this is what i want.

Comment: yes i did like that only. have you test above code ?

Comment: Tested but not achieving result

Comment: Put something else in the `error404.php`. Like just a simple `echo "This is 404";`. Currently, that `header("Location: ")` will just send them back to `index.php`

Comment: Its Working in my sever. Check your config @Khurram

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this in PHP, but you can do this easily with your server's `.htaccess` file. Just add the following code to it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Or, if you have a specific error-handling page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?err=404
```

Or something like that, depending on how you set up the error-handling page.

This wil redirect any request to a non-existing file to the `index.php` or `error.php` files in the root directory.

Comment: not working because index.php is exists so I think its not a 404 error.

Comment: want to handle index.php/somefile.php 
*somefile.php not exists